# Viewstate does not persist after postback

Tags: .net, vb.net, viewstate, page-lifecycle

I'm having some problems in persisting the viewstate on postback for a Control (vb.net)

here's some code i've put in my control:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            MyBase.OnInit(e)
            Me.EnableViewState = True
            Me.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Enabled
            If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
                _SortTime = DateTime.Now
                _SortTime.AddSeconds(-10) ' incase the fileserver and webserver date are out of sync
                ViewState("PageLoadTimeStamp") = _SortTime      
            End If
        End Sub
```

onload:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)

        _SortTime = CType(ViewState("PageLoadTimeStamp"), DateTime)

End Sub
```

But on every postback, the viewstate is empty again.

**Update**: What do i want to do?
I want to store the time when the user first loads the page. Then, the user will do multiple postbacks. On every postback i need to know that time.

**Update 2:** Context:

- An aspx page (Editor.aspx) will load a web control (ObjectsEditor.ascx) dynamicly
- ObjectsEditor.ascx contains of a single custom control (Objects.vb)
- Objects.vb will create another custom control (ObjectsContainer.vb) and add it to it's controls
  It is the ObjectsContainer that needs to persist the viewstate.

I'm setting EnableViewState = "true" everywhere i can, but still no result. Do i really need to set those properties here. (ViewStateMode and EnableViewState) If not, where should i handle this and what is the difference between those properties?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find why the viewstate did not persist after postback, but I've found another way to hold the value using the controlstate. Here's my implementation:

```
 Public Property SortTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return _SortTime
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DateTime)
            _SortTime = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Add the following overridden methods:

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Page.RegisterRequiresControlState(Me)
        MyBase.OnInit(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function SaveControlState() As Object
        Return _SortTime
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub LoadControlState(ByVal savedState As Object)
        Dim state As DateTime = CType(savedState, DateTime)
        Me._SortTime = state
    End Sub
```

Give a value to the property in OnLoad

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            SortTime = DateTime.Now
        End If
    End Sub
```

Now i can call the property after the page has loaded and it will always have the value set on the first page load. It will not change on postback and it won't be gone on postback.

I'm sure this is possible with the viewstate too, but for some reason, this was not working for me.

Thanks for helping me to understand the Viewstate, I'm sure i'll have to use the viewstate sooner or later.

Answer (score 7):

I see some correct answers here, but I don't see any detailed explanations, so I figured I would chime in:

ASP.NET has a fairly complicated request/response life-cycle. Each cycle runs through a set of events such as `Init`, `Load`, etc.. According to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), and specifically [this image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC386473.png), there is a method called `TrackViewState()` that executes after the `Init` event but before `InitComplete` event. This means that any changes to `ViewState` will not be persisted (tracked) if they are made in the `Init` event like the OP has done.

There is an additional method called `LoadViewState()` that takes the `ViewState` data that was posted via the `__VIEWSTATE` form value and loads it into the current `ViewState` collection. This executes after the `InitComplete` event but before the `PreLoad` event. Meaning that values already set to `ViewState` before `LoadViewState()` executes will likely be overwritten.

Now, knowing when these 2 events occur, and knowing the `ViewState` persistence methods that execute before and after them, we can deduce that the earliest event where it is safe to set `ViewState` values is the `PreLoad` event. Values set earlier than this event will likely be overwritten and thus not persisted.

So, to answer your question, set your `ViewState` value in the `OnPreLoad()` method or do as others have suggested and do it in the `OnLoad()` method and your values should be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

The page's `ViewState` will not be loaded until [`Load`-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.load.aspx). So you can store your value but not reload it in `OnInit`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

**Edit**: To be honest, i'm yet not sure what causes your issue(and have not the time to investigate further), but try this way which works as expected:

```
Private Property SortTime As Date
    Get
        If ViewState("PageLoadTimeStamp") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("PageLoadTimeStamp") = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-10)
        End If
        Return DirectCast(ViewState("PageLoadTimeStamp"), Date)
    End Get
    Set(value As Date)
        ViewState("PageLoadTimeStamp") = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnInit(e)
    'Me.EnableViewState = True
    'Me.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Enabled
    'If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    '    _SortTime = DateTime.Now
    '    _SortTime.AddSeconds(-10) ' incase the fileserver and webserver date are out of sync
    '    ViewState("PageLoadTimeStamp") = _SortTime
    'End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    Dim time = SortTime
    '_SortTime = CType(ViewState("PageLoadTimeStamp"), DateTime)
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok. I'll move the load viewstate part to the onload. I'll let you know in a minute.

Comment: It's not working with moving the load viewstate to the onload method. Do you have another idea that may help me?

Comment: @ThomasDekiere: Edited my answer to provide another working approach with a property. I've commented out your code which is redundant now(hopefully). Note that the line `Dim time = SortTime` is just for demonstrating purposes, actually it's also redundant.

Comment: Oh no. Still wrong. It does not give me the time when the page has first loaded. It'll give me a new time on every postback :(

Comment: @ThomasDekiere: Up to now it was working but not anymore? It's working for me, just generating one time and always the same on the following postbacks. I've tested it with a simple UserControl. Maybe you need to give more details. What kind of control is this, how are you reloading the page, is anything created dynamically and where is this control nested? You could try to override [`control.LoadViewState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.loadviewstate.aspx)(first call `base.LoadViewState`) to read it.

Comment: For example, if it's nested in a databound control(like GridView) that you're databinding on postbacks, ViewState will be lost. Also note that `EnableViewState` will be inherited from parent to child controls(e.g. you've set a GridView `EnableViewState=false` and declared this control in one of its TemplateFields, then your controll will inherit this setting even if you set `EnableViewState=true`).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9148/discussion-between-thomas-dekiere-and-tim-schmelter)

Answer (score 0):

When a postback happens (i.e. when a form is submitted to a server), the variable values that are set in the code-behind page are erased from the memory of the client system

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfx64bit/thread/961985e8-37fe-4b0d-8eb9-9920e4b298d7/

Comment: Read the second paragraph of that article. That's what i'm trying to do here. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.EnableViewState = True
    Me.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Enabled             
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        _SortTime = DateTime.Now                 
        _SortTime.AddSeconds(-10) ' incase the fileserver and webserver date are out of sync                 
         ViewState("PageLoadTimeStamp") = _SortTime                   
    End If 
End Sub
```

Write this code

Comment: thats optional and depends on your logic

Comment: I've done this and moved loading the viewstate to the onload part of the control. But still the same result. Viewstate is nothing after postback.