# OnServerClick with dynamic anchorlink not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to fire an OnServerClick event from some anchor tag created dynamically. My event isn't firing from my anchor tag. i have no error.

Can someone help me ?

```
HtmlAnchor btn_close = new HtmlAnchor();
btn_close.Attributes.Add("class", "close");
btn_close.Attributes.Add("data-dismiss", "alert");
btn_close.Attributes.Add("aria-label", "Ne plus afficher");
btn_close.Attributes.Add("title", "Ne plus afficher");
btn_close.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
btn_close.ServerClick += new EventHandler(hideNotificationBtn_Click);
btn_close.ID = notificationSent.NotificationSentID.ToString();
btn_close.InnerText = "test";

div_alert.Controls.Add(btn_close);
```

```
        protected void hideNotificationBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlAnchor cb = (HtmlAnchor)sender;
            int test = int.Parse(cb.Name);
            NotificationSent.SetNotificationAsHidden(int.Parse(cb.Name));
        }
```

My hide notification isn't fired from by anchor when i click on it.
I already tried to change it to a button.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors don't call server side functions even when they are runat server, however there is the LinkButton class that can be used instead. Ultimately it is rendered as JavaScript initiated postback. Check out https://forums.asp.net/p/1519048/3644158.aspx for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are creating that button early enough in the page lifecycle. Look to get it created OnInit of the Page.

This is because the event handling events happen after Page Init. Of course, the button has to have been created before the events can be detected on

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (ViewState["falg"] != null)
        {
            Create();
        }

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Create();
    ViewState.Add("falg", true);
}

void BtnServices_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("hi");
}

void BtnServices_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("hi");
}
void Create()
{
    BtnServices = new Button();
    BtnServices.ID = "BtnServices";
    BtnServices.Text = "Click Me";
    BtnServices.Click += new EventHandler(BtnServices_Click);
    BtnServices.Command += new CommandEventHandler(BtnServices_Command);
    form1.Controls.Add(BtnServices);
}
```

> Easier and reliable way to do this could be , instead of dynamically
>   adding the control, always add it, but set Visible=false initially.
>   Then where you're currently adding it, instead just make it visible.

Comment: When you do postback, viewstate will lost. I think so it is not correct solution.

Comment: There are workarounds to retain the view state during the page lifecycle. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802994/10907141)

Comment: Not working on my side, the event doesn't want to raise